# Duplicate changelogs in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am working on how to use the new Jenkins Pipeline Plugin with the `Jenkinsfile` in the scm of the project (we use GIT).

The job script is loaded from the SCM ('Pipeline script from SCM' option)
and in the `Jenkinsfile` script I do a `checkout scm`.

The problem is that the commits are duplicated. In the build directory, there is 2 `changelog.xml` with the same commits and so the changes view can be very messy :

```
Summary

1. FNC71010 - Ajout des traductions au launcher (details)
Commit 5a676ee1448b72f1b99227e8832b01081aa1bc6d by thierry
The file was modified   Deploy_serveur/resources/config/trad.properties

Summary

1.FNC71010 - Ajout des traductions au launcher (details)
Commit 5a676ee1448b72f1b99227e8832b01081aa1bc6d by thierry
The file was modified   Deploy_serveur/resources/config/trad.properties
```

The problem occurs also with in the multibranch pipeline.

Here is the `Jenkinsfile` content :

```
#!groovy

node {
    stage 'initialisation'
    def repertoire = "directory"

    def pipeline
    dir(repertoire) {
        checkout scm
        pipeline = load 'pipeline.groovy'
    }
    pipeline.initialisation(repertoire)
    pipeline.build()
    pipeline.runTestsRapides()
    pipeline.copieResultats()
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Jenkins version : 1.642.2 (docker)
Pipeline version : 1.15
Git plugin : 2.4.3

Comment: If you look in the console, do you see a git checkout twice?

Comment: Yes, one from the Jenkins job, one from the pipeline script. But it looks like the [method recommended by Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multibranch-projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try upgrading the Git plugin to 2.4.4?

Comment: (back from a long week-end). I upgraded the Git plugin to 2.4.4 and on the command `checkout scm` does not duplicate the commit anymore.

Comment: Great, then the refix of JENKINS-29326 worked. [changelog](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)