# Duplicate changelogs in jenkins pipeline script with SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

This question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197131/duplicate-changelogs-in-jenkins-pipeline-script) except I'm using subversion, and no plugin update has done the trick for me.

I'm loading my Jenkinsfile script with a multibranch pipeline setting, and the changelog gets duplicated at each new `checkout scm`.

Since in my build I'm using multiple workspaces, allocated through `node` inside `parallel` blocks, I'm calling fresh checkouts for each of them, and the changelog duplication is getting a bit annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facing the same problem.

I am doing the following, until a fix for the SVN plug-in is released.

```
currentBuild.getChangeSets().clear()
checkout scm
```

Attention: you might have to approve the script calls via the "In-process Script approval" page.

This will clear the changelog from the Jenkins Job. The changelog will be filled again by the 'checkout scm' call.
**UPDATE: Check my edit below. This "solution" does not work, because adds back the removed revisions after a restart ... i don't get why, but ...**

EDIT:

OK now I found a new way:

```
for(i = 0; i < scm.getLocations().length; i++) {
        def location = scm.getLocations()[i]
        def svn_url = location.remote
        checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '252ad9ab-2f39-46f5-a77a-6196d1679dee', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: svn_url]], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateWithRevertUpdater']]
    }
```

You should use the "Pipeline Syntax" page to get the credentials right.
i tried using just

```
checkout changelog: false, scm
```

but that didn't work. So you have to use the long version shown above.

Comment: Thanks for proposing a workaround, I'll try it as soon as I come back to work from holidays.

Comment: Found out a nasty thing ... If Jenkins is restarted, it seems to rebuild the changesets and adds the formerly deleted back to the build :(
Just discovered after an update and restart ...

Comment: what I was missing was the 'changelog: false', all the rest I figured out already. Thanks mate, great answer

Comment: ```checkout scm: scm, changelog: false```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than redefining the SCM class, one can still refer to the original "scm" object and disable the changelog like so:

```
checkout(changelog: false, scm: scm)
```

This will retain the intended behviour of "checkout scm" while disabling the changelog generation.

Comment: Does work now, thanks :)
Did not work back then, when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ben Herfurth's answer is good, I'll just post my final adaptation for it because I tried to wrap it up a bit in a single working function.

This function works for me as I have only one SVN repository to checkout, and everything else (e.g. passwords) have been configured already:

```
def checkout(){
    def svnLocation = scm.locations[0]
    checkout(changelog: false, scm: [$class: 'SubversionSCM', locations: [svnLocation], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateWithCleanUpdater']])  
}
```

I just drop a call to this everywhere I need a fresh working copy.

```
node('linux') {        
   checkout()
   // ... run ITs on linux ...
}

node('windows') {
   checkout() // doesn't duplicate changelog anymore
   // ... run ITs on windows ....
}
```

Hope this helps others.